# Examples of smooth stochastic processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Consider a continuous-time stochastic process $X(t)$. $X(t)$ is $L^2$-continuous if and only if

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\ \mathbb{E}\left(\left(X(t+h) - X(t)\right)^2\right) = 0$$

Similarly, we can define the $L^2$ derivative of $X(t)$, $\frac{dX(t)}{dt}$, as the stochastic process that satisfies the following equality, when such a process exists and is unique:

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\ \mathbb{E}\left(\left(\frac{dX(t)}{dt} - \frac{X(t+h) - X(t)}{h}\right)^2\right)= 0$$

$X(t)$ is $L^2$ smooth if all of its derivatives in time are continuous.

**Are there any simple and/or widely used examples of smooth continuous-time stochastic processes?**